# ajax request to python script

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

i just tested out a script i made. it is in python. i use ajax, to send a request and try and get the result.

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;
    var e = document.getElementById("ktype");
    var ktype = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var acookie = document.getElementById("acookie").value;
alert (ktype +"\n" + acookie);
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState < 4){
            document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = "<center><img src='loading.gif' style='max-width:60px; max-height:60px;'></center>";
        }
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "kindle.py", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.send("amzcookie=" + acookie + "&ktype=" + ktype);
}
```

the python script uses CGI. no web framework like django.

when i do this request it just prints the contents of the python file. no code is executed.

Comment: Can you post the Python code? The JS isn't really relevant.

Comment: Ditto on posting the Python code. It would also be helpful to have some information on your server setup beyond it being "CGI". Could you provide some information about what server you're running and the relevant portion of its config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `JQuery` for that ... instead of writing your own `Ajax` request, it can be written in a line:

```
$.post('link-to-my-python-script',{data},
          function(answer){
                      // process your request here ..
                  });
```

You can read more about that here: [JqueryPost](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)